# How to separate words by spaces?

Tags: java, string

What I'm trying to do in this code is separate each word of a five-word input into the five words that it's made of. I managed to get the first word separated from the rest of the input using indexOf and substring, but I have problems separating the rest of the words. I am just wondering what I could do to fix this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CryptographyLab {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        fiveWords();
    }

    public static void fiveWords () {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            if (i > 1) {
                String clear = input.nextLine(); 
                // I was having some problems with the input buffer not clearing, and I know this is a funky way to clear it but my skills are pretty limited wher I am right now 
            }

            System.out.print("Enter five words: ");
            String fW = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println();
            // What I'm trying to do here is separate a Scanner input into each word, by finding the index of the space. 

            int sF = fW.indexOf(" ");
            String fS = fW.substring(0, sF);

            System.out.println(fS);

            int dF = fW.indexOf(" ");
            String fD = fW.substring(sF, dF);

            System.out.println(fD);

            int gF = fW.indexOf(" ");
            String fG = fW.substring(dF, gF);

            //I stopped putting println commands here because it wasn't working.
            int hF = fW.indexOf(" ");
            String fH = fW.substring(gF, hF);

            int jF = fW.indexOf(" ");
            String fJ = fW.substring(hF, jF);

            System.out.print("Enter five integers: ");
            int fI = input.nextInt();
            int f2 = input.nextInt();
            int f3 = input.nextInt();
            int f4 = input.nextInt();
            int f5 = input.nextInt();
            //this part is unimportant because I haven't worked out the rest yet

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`Scanner` class has a `next()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) that returns the next "token" from the input. In this case, I think calling `next()` five times in succession should return your 5 words.

As Alex Yan points out in his answer, you can also use the `split` method on a string to split on some delimiter (in this case, a space).

Answer (score 0):

You're extracting the strings incorrectly. But there is another simpler solution which I'll explain after.

The problem with your approach is that you're not supplying the indices correctly.

After the first round of extraction:

```
fW = "this should be five words"
sf = indexOf(" ") = 4
fS = fW.substring(0, sF) = "this"
```

This appears correct. But after the second round:

```
fW = "this should be five words". Nothing changed
df = indexOf(" ") = 4. Same as above
fD = fW.substring(sF, dF) = substring(4, 4). You get a null string
```

We see that the problem is because `indexOf()` finds the first occurrence of the supplied substring. `substring()` doesn't remove the portion that you substring. If you want to keep doing it this way, you should trim off the word you just substringed.

```
space = input.indexOf(" ");
firstWord = input.substring(0, space);
input = input.substring(space).trim(); // sets input to "should be five words" so that indexOf() looks for the next space during the next round
```

---

A simple solution is to just use `String.split()` to split this into an array of substrings.

```
String[] words = fw.split(" ");
```

If input is "this should be five words"

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; ++i)
    System.out.println(words[i]);
```

Should print:

```
this
should
be
five
words
```